# Shopware 6 Administration: How to fetch data from table with where custom_fields.value

Tags: mysql, database, shopware, shopware6

To my custom plugin i've already [added a column `custom_fields`](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/custom-field/add-custom-field) in table `my_plugin` and filled with data:

```
// table data my_plugin.custom_fields

{
   "parent":{
      "active":true
   }
}
```

To count `id`'s from table `my_plugin`, the working query looks like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM my_plugin WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(custom_fields, '$.parent.active') = true; // return 1
```

But i can't find, [which or how to use Criteria](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/integrations-api/general-concepts/search-criteria#filter). My attempt returns `totad: 0`:

```
...
criteria
    .addFilter(
        Criteria.equals('customFields.parent.active', true)
    )
...   
this.myPluginRepository
    .search(criteria, Shopware.Context.api)
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result) // return result.total: 0
    })
```

The provided doc [Fetching data from "entity selection" custom field](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/custom-field/fetching-data-from-entity-selection) seems does nothing to do with the example of [Add custom field](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/custom-field/add-custom-field), at least for me...

**What is the right way to count id's by filtered json using Criteria?**

**EDIT 1**
one dimensional json works, like this (dummy):

```
{"test": "test"}

...
Criteria.equals('customFields.test', 'test') // return the right record
...
```

Seems it **failes on multidimensional json**

**EDIT 2**
the provided query, which return 0 records:

```
SELECT
  `my_plugin`.`id`
FROM
  `my_plugin`
WHERE
  (
    IF(
      JSON_TYPE(
        JSON_EXTRACT(
          `my_plugin`.`custom_fields`,
          '$.parent.active'
        )
      ) != "NULL",
      CONVERT(
        JSON_UNQUOTE(
          JSON_EXTRACT(
            `my_plugin`.`custom_fields`,
            '$.parent.active'
          )
        ) USING "utf8mb4"
      ) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
      NULL
    ) = :param_d1eb98b8285a4dfd9fc4df46453b4022
  )
LIMIT
  25
```

Btw, the Criteria for the provided request above is:

```
Criteria.equals('customFields.test', 'test')
```

Why the request search `!= NULL` instead `test`?

Comment: What do you mean by multidimensional JSON? The SQL code you are seeing might come from here: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/428928e9c42ba4df09d8ee619bff01612bfa112b/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Dbal/FieldAccessorBuilder/JsonFieldAccessorBuilder.php#L76 and it seems for handling the NULL values properly. You parameter "test" is probably stored in `:param_d1eb98b8285a4dfd9fc4df46453b4022` if you debug it, so nothing seems to be wrong here. Can you make your question more clear?